# Ошибка при подключении библиотеки boost с помощью cmake. Не могу запустить пример с boost org

Tags: c++, cmake, boost, build

Info: `cmake version 3.20.1` & `libboost1.71-dev` & `Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.`

Сборка:

```
 user@:~/CLionProjects/testBoost/build$ cmake ..

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/CLionProjects/testBoost/build

user@:~/CLionProjects/testBoost/build$ make

Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target main
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/boost/beast/core/detail/bind_handler.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/include/boost/beast/core/bind_handler.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/beast/core/async_base.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/beast/core.hpp:15,
                 from /home/user/CLionProjects/testBoost/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/asio/associated_allocator.hpp:39:39: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
   39 |   static type get(const T&, const E& e) BOOST_ASIO_NOEXCEPT
      |                                       ^
      |                                        ;
/usr/include/boost/asio/associated_allocator.hpp:39:41: error: ‘BOOST_ASIO_NOEXCEPT’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘BOOST_NOEXCEPT’?
   39 |   static type get(const T&, const E& e) BOOST_ASIO_NOEXCEPT
      |                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                         BOOST_NOEXCEPT
/usr/include/boost/asio/associated_allocator.hpp:51:39: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
   51 |   static type get(const T& t, const E&) BOOST_ASIO_NOEXCEPT
      |                                       ^
      |                                        ;
/usr/include/boost/asio/associated_allocator.hpp:51:41: error: ‘BOOST_ASIO_NOEXCEPT’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘BOOST_NOEXCEPT’?
   51 |   static type get(const T& t, const E&) BOOST_ASIO_NOEXCEPT
      |                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                         BOOST_NOEXCEPT
```

cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(main)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package (Boost REQUIRED)

if (Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif ()

add_executable(main main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(main ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/version.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/connect.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace beast = boost::beast;     // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http = beast::http;       // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace net = boost::asio;        // from <boost/asio.hpp>
using tcp = net::ip::tcp;           // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try
    {
        // Check command line arguments.
        if(argc != 4 && argc != 5)
        {
            std::cerr <<
                      "Usage: http-client-sync <host> <port> <target> [<HTTP version: 1.0 or 1.1(default)>]\n" <<
                      "Example:\n" <<
                      "    http-client-sync www.example.com 80 /\n" <<
                      "    http-client-sync www.example.com 80 / 1.0\n";
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        auto const host = argv[1];
        auto const port = argv[2];
        auto const target = argv[3];
        int version = argc == 5 && !std::strcmp("1.0", argv[4]) ? 10 : 11;

        // The io_context is required for all I/O
        net::io_context ioc;

        // These objects perform our I/O
        tcp::resolver resolver(ioc);
        beast::tcp_stream stream(ioc);

        // Look up the domain name
        auto const results = resolver.resolve(host, port);

        // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
        stream.connect(results);

        // Set up an HTTP GET request message
        http::request<http::string_body> req{http::verb::get, target, version};
        req.set(http::field::host, host);
        req.set(http::field::user_agent, BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);

        // Send the HTTP request to the remote host
        http::write(stream, req);

        // This buffer is used for reading and must be persisted
        beast::flat_buffer buffer;

        // Declare a container to hold the response
        http::response<http::dynamic_body> res;

        // Receive the HTTP response
        http::read(stream, buffer, res);

        // Write the message to standard out
        std::cout << res << std::endl;

        // Gracefully close the socket
        beast::error_code ec;
        stream.socket().shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ec);

        // not_connected happens sometimes
        // so don't bother reporting it.
        //
        if(ec && ec != beast::errc::not_connected)
            throw beast::system_error{ec};

        // If we get here then the connection is closed gracefully
    }
    catch(std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Хотя к примеру вот это запускается и работает:

```
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  typedef boost::array<std::string, 3> array;
  array a;

  a[0] = "cat";
  a.at(1) = "shark";
  *a.rbegin() = "spider";

  std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());

  for (const std::string &s : a)
    std::cout << s << '\n';

  std::cout << a.size() << '\n';
  std::cout << a.max_size() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: хм, а зачем было удалять старый вопрос? я попробовал собрать Ваш пример, для полной компиляции пришлось добавить `find_package(Threads REQUIRED)` и правильно подлинковал. Думаю, Вы криво собрали буст

Comment: @KoVadim вроде одной коммандой ставил `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`

Comment: @KoVadim как мне проверить и собрать его правильно? Я просто слабоват в этом

Comment: @KoVadim можете скинуть вашу версию cmake под мой проект?

Comment: у меня 3.16.Думаю, проблема в сборке буста

Comment: @KoVadim я скинул сборку буста внизу, вроде ведь все верно, нет?

Comment: А Вам точно вот нужно собирать свой буст? Чем тот, который идет с дистрибутивом не подходит?

Comment: @KoVadim я просто хочу чтобы пример заработал и потыкать буст, как это сделать)

Comment: используйте буст, который идет с Вашим дистрибутивом. Это самый надежный и лучший способ. Пересобирать буст есть смысл тогда, когда больше нечем заняться или Вы разработчик буста. Если у Вас убунта или дебиан, тогда установите пакет libboost-dev и все будет по стандартным путям.

Comment: @KoVadim по стандартным путям вроде `usr/local/include/boost` и `usr/local/lib` ?
Так я уже пытался так делать, просто поставил `sudo apt install libboost-dev` прописал эти пути и ошибки те же...

Comment: а не нужно прописывать пути. Если же ошибка все равно возникает, тогда пишите версии буста, ОС и компилятора. А ещё лучше установите cmake отдельно (я просто случайно увидел, что компилируется это с под clion - давайте и его исключим из процесса, мало чего там настроено)

Comment: @KoVadim `cmake version 3.20.1` & `libboost1.71-dev` `Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS`.

Comment: На одном с моих серверов все такое же. И оно работает. Вангую на cmake от CLion

Comment: @KoVadim добавил внизу ответ с логом из командной строки и сборкой без clion:)

Comment: Зачем добавлять ответом то, что ответом на поставленный вопрос не является?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я недавно на stackoverflow и когда добавляешь ответ то его можно редактировать, а тут в комментариях неудобно редактировать, извиняюсь

Comment: @lbsmart так надо сам вопрос редактировать через ссылку [edit], а не "ответы" писать, которые ответами не являются. И всё будет норм.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ понял, не знал, исправлюсь

Comment: @lbsmart, вопрос можно редактировать добавляя в него информацию, не нужно писать ответы как дополнение к вопросу .

Comment: @こきん я исправил